# All commands in irb giving "NoMethodError: undefined method `write' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby, irb

I am trying to get the current ruby version from IRB but its giving me this error:

```
>> RUBY_VERSION
NoMethodError: undefined method `write' for nil:NilClass
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `printf'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `output_value'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:160:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156:in `block in eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ext/multi-irb.rb:166:in `block (2 levels) in irb'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ext/multi-irb.rb:165:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ext/multi-irb.rb:165:in `block in irb'
Maybe IRB bug!
```

`ruby -v` shows `ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]`

I am using `Mac OS X Lion`

**UPDATE:**
Actually, it doesn't run anything at all.

```
>> a = 'Hello, World!'
NoMethodError: undefined method `write' for nil:NilClass
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `printf'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:311:in `output_value'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:160:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156:in `block in eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ext/multi-irb.rb:166:in `block (2 levels) in irb'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ext/multi-irb.rb:165:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ext/multi-irb.rb:165:in `block in irb'
Maybe IRB bug!
```

**UPDATE # 2:** (For the Tin Man)
Using /usr/bin/irb, I get

```
>> 5+5
NoMethodError: undefined method `write' for nil:NilClass
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:310:in `printf'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:310:in `output_value'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:159:in `eval_input'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/ruby-lex.rb:244:in `each_top_level_statement'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/ruby-lex.rb:230:in `loop'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/ruby-lex.rb:230:in `each_top_level_statement'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `catch'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `each_top_level_statement'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `catch'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
    from /usr/bin/irb:13
Maybe IRB bug!!
```

Comment: What does `ruby -v` show when you run it at a command line?  What OS are you using?  Does your `irb` work at all?  Do you have a .irbrc file?

Comment: updated my question with more info.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: IRB on Lion should be in `/usr/bin/irb`, not based in `/usr/local/...` so you are running on a modified Mac OS. 

How did you install 1.9.3?

Comment: Mac OS X came with 1.8.7. I installed 1.9.3 by following this guide: http://hivelogic.com/articles/ruby-rails-leopard/

Comment: So you installed Ruby on Lion using the instructions for Leopard.

Comment: I thought it would be the same thing, guess it wasn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `/usr/bin/irb` to get to Apple's installation of Ruby.

Installing Ruby on Lion using instructions for Leopard isn't a good idea. You have to remember that languages and OS details change.

The information at "[Building Ruby 1.9.3 on Lion with Xcode 4.2 using ./configure --with-gcc=clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956320/building-ruby-1-9-3-on-lion-with-xcode-4-2-using-configure-with-gcc-clang)" should help. Also "[Error installing 1.9.3 with RVM on Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675194/error-installing-1-9-3-with-rvm-on-lion)" has useful information about XCode.

Comment: I mean, try typing that in at the command-line and see what it does. Apple pre-installs Ruby for their own use and `/usr/bin/irb` is their instance of IRB. If it works you know your installation of 1.9.3 is hosed and you need to follow different directions.

Comment: Ah. just did. I get long error. I'll update my question with the new log.

Comment: Because two different versions of Ruby, one of which is Apple's build, are showing identical problems, I suspect the problem isn't Ruby but something else in your system. Have there been any other changes to your OS, such as installing other command-line applications or replacing any libraries?